# better way store friends and retrieve friends of a particular user

Tags: mysql, database, performance, database-design

Which of these mysql storage methods would be faster to query (to retrieve friends of a particular user say @anyid):

```
Table: Friends

Columns: friend1 friend2
```

insert only one row per friendship and query as

```
select friend1 
from FRIENDS 
where friend2=@anyid
UNION ALL
select friend2 
from FRIENDS 
where friend1=@anyid
```

OR

insert two rows per friendship (insert as friend1 friend2 and then insert swapped entries eg, 1,2 and 2,1) and then simply query as

```
select friend2 from FRIENDS where friend1=@anyid
```

to me it seems the second method will perform better since it requires indexing on only a single column friend1 and a single query. The first method may require both columns to be indexed and requires running two sub queries. But in some posts i see people claiming the first method may perform better. 
On the plus side the first method will take half the storage when compared to the second method, would that make a huge difference for say million records.

Also one other thing, is it required to even store a seperate `relationship_id` and `creation_date` for any of the two methods above. what could be the exceptional benefit i would get other than giving me the relationship creation time or sequence, i think most people should be able to live without it or not?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: I would expect the 2nd to perform more quickly at the expense of using more storage. The first has the overhead of eliminating duplicates (or attempting to) for the UNION, although you can probably use UNION ALL to remove that.

Comment: so even with UNION ALL in the first query still the second one would be faster right? (also editing the same in the question. thanks!)

Comment: What I am not sure about is if you needed to join via such a query whether MySQL would make best use of the indexes.

Comment: are you referring to nosql. for just one join wouldnt mysql suffice, for even million users...

Comment: For a query where you have a user and want their details and all the details for their friends. So you would have to join the users against your table of user friends, and then that back against the users table. Not sure how efficiently MySQL would use indexes on the when joining against the sub select of the user friends table.

Comment: A further down side of a single record to go both ways is if you want relationships where A is a friend of B, but B is not a friend of A (yet).

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. For you previous comment what would be a better replacement for mysql for this issue would it be a nosql solution like graph db or a doc store or something else you are pointing to. Thanks!

Comment: Afraid I am not really familiar with any nosql solutions, but I would be happy enough using MySQL for this.

Comment: oh ok i thought you were pointing in some direction. Anyways Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me, the fundamental question is:  "How many friendships are in the database?"  If only A and B are friends, is the number "1" or "2".  This answer dictates how you understand the friendship entity and hence how it should be implemented.

There is definitely a difference in the two approaches.  To count the number of friends in the first way:

```
select count(*)
from friends
where USERID in (friend1, friend2);
```

versus:

```
select count(*)
from friends
where USERID = friend1;
```

The second can more easily take advantage of an index on `friend1` and can be optimized to be faster than the first.

On the other hand, inserting a record takes twice as long.  And finding friends of friends (and so on) requires handling more data and hence more processing time.

The friendship relationship does have additional characteristics, such as who initiated the request (this would often be `friend1` in the first approach).  Or the times the friendship was requested and accepted. Such additional information suggests the first approach to eliminate the duplication of data.

In other words, the question about the data structure -- as with almost all such questions -- is answered by how you understand the entities and how they are going to be used.

Comment: so do you think once the data grows the two row data model would start giving performance issues for querying due to its larger size. For  friends of friends case the two row method seems to be faster although i think for a large number users it may be slower as it has to handle a large datasize as you said. For FOF would it be too slow to use this model or would it be just a few seconds slower -any ideas - I am actually looking for model that can handle say a million users.

Comment: W.r.t the last part i am not planning to store relationship information i have not seen this info in any of the websites and doesnt make much sense to me to give this info to the endusers or keep this info internal.

Comment: @DevD . . . My suggestion is that you mock up some data with a million rows and try sample queries on them.  If your interest is strictly performance on certain queries, then having a mocked data set lets you answer the question specifically for your needs.

Comment: agreed...is there any synthetic opensource/free tools to use for such kind of drills? loading up million users would require me to arrange for that much space which requires budget. (leasing of servers and testing would be available to me only at a later stage). Thanks!

Comment: @DevD . . . The resources required are tiny.  A table of a million users with the friendships would be measured in, at most, hundreds of megabytes.  The user id would be 4 bytes (4 Mbytes).  The friendship table would have three ids (always include a primary key!).  So, 10 million friends would be about 120 Mbytes.  You can download MySQL for free and test easily on a laptop.  Not a perfect replica of the environment, but a no-additional resources approach to get used to the data structures and queries.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the info. will test it. Also you stress on a seperate primary key. Is there any disadvantage on using the two friendids as primary key since the combination would be always unique.

Comment: @DevD . . . In my experience, I have developed a strong preference for an auto incremented primary key on every table.  This makes it easier to remove duplicates, should any be inadvertently created.  It makes it possible to order rows by insertion time, should that prove useful.  And it provides a simple key to another table, should it want to reference the friendship table.  Not required, but I always include it.